# Using ReCaptcha with jquery Validation Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation, recaptcha

I have a form that utilizes query.validate.js to perform field validation before submitting the form. It works, but now I'm trying to a Recaptcha 2.0 (the cool one where you just click a button). However, the form is being submitted without checking the ReCaptcha box. I'm assuming they are conflicting with each other somehow?

```
<head>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<form id="register" name="register" action="ce/ce_register_process.php" method="post" >

 <p>FIELD:<br/>
        <input id="field" size="40" name="field" type="text" required>
      </p>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxx"></div>

<input type="submit" value="Enter">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        $("#register").validate({
            rules: {

                first: "required",
                last: "required",
                password: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    required: true  
                },
                password2: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    required: true,
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }

            }
        })
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: if you know the problem is the jqery conflict, have you tried jquery.noConflict?

Comment: I only suspect that might be the issue. I did try adding $.noConflict(); at the top of my script and it had no effect.